# Getting an exception in kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm getting an exception:

> {"At least one object must implement IComparable."}

when I'm doing sorting specific column wise in kendo grid

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<xxy>)(Model))
 .Name("technologyGrid")
      columns.Bound(skills => skills.Employees).Title("Number of Tagged Employees").Template(
         @<label>
             @{
                 var total = item.Employees.Count();
                 @Html.Label(total.ToString())
             }
         </label>).Width(50);
       columns.Bound(skills => skills.Projects).Title("Number of Tagged Projects").Template(
         @<label>
             @{
                 var total = item.Projects.Count();
                 @Html.Label(total.ToString())
             }
         </label>).Width(50);

   })
      .Scrollable()
      .Pageable(pageable => pageable)
      .Refresh(true)
      .PageSizes(true)
      .ButtonCount(5))
      .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
```

How can I resolve this exception?

Answer (score 0):

The value you bind the column to becomes the default sort value for the column when sorting. Your employee and project need a comparer function or you need to find another way you want to sort the columns(name or id). Simple types that do not need to implement IComparable (string, int, etc) are automatically sorted.

Adding calculated count or sort order fields to your skills list would work:

```
columns.Bound(skills => skills.EmployeeCount)
columns.Bound(skills => skills.ProjectCount)
```

...

I haven't tried this, however, it might work:

```
columns.Bound(skills => skills.Employees.Count)
```